# EJB3 Singleton Session Bean and ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: singleton, ejb-3.1, concurrenthashmap

If using a EJB3 Singleton Session Bean, there is no point to having ConcurrentHashMap state variable - correct?  I can just use a regular HashMap that will be managed by the Container Concurrency Manager ?

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. If nothing else is specified, by default singleton session bean uses container managed concurrency. Further, if not specified, every business and timeout method have by default LockType.WRITE. Result is that there is not multiple threads concurrently executing methods in singleton and as consequence using regular java.util.HashMap is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

The default is `@ConcurrencyManagement(CONTAINER)` with `@Lock(WRITE)` for all methods, which won't scale as nicely as a `ConcurrentHashMap` since all method calls will block waiting for the write lock.  You could use `@Lock(READ)` and `ConcurrentHashMap` to allow multiple threads, but at that point, you might as well use `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` to get rid of the container-managed concurrency altogether.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Thanks for your help, it was very useful.

Comment: @JasonH If the answer solved your problem, you should accept it (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).